# Dataset shows in Hive is inconsistent with JDBC

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to query data from Hive in spark. According the [spark-sql](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html), there're two ways to do this:

The first way is Init session with `enableHiveSupport`

```
SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();

session.sql("select dw_date from tfdw.dwd_dim_date limit 10").show();
```

the dataset shows the correct result
[image]

The second way is through JDBC

```
Dataset<Row> ds = session.read()
                  .format("jdbc")
                  .option("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")
                  .option("url", "jdbc:hive2://iZ11syxr6afZ:21050/;auth=noSasl")
                  .option("dbtable", "tfdw.dwd_dim_date")
                  .load();
        
ds.select("dw_date").limit(10).show();
```

But the dataset only show the column name in the result rather than the data of the column.
[image]

The two pictures should be consistent I think. Any outstanding I missed ? Many thanks!

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. You should write a bug report in the Spark JIRA. 
( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22101?jql=project%20%3D%20SPARK )
Don't forget to precise the version of Spark that you are using.
I tried to reproduce your issue on spark 2.2.0 with a SparkThriftServer instead of a HiveServer2, and I got something wrong too, but in a different way: when I query a table via jdbc, I get 0 rows, even though I get the correct column names and the ThriftServer logs a query returning some rows. Strange indeed...

Comment: @FurryMachine Thanks for show me the url of JIRA. Please refer to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22113
Feel free to comment.

Comment: @FurryMachine Just an update from JIRA. They recognize communicate with Hive via JDBC does not work currently. But they are not sure whether spark would support this since varied Hive version cause different result. And JDBC with Hive is not recommended. So I close that issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Indeed there are some versioning issues with the Hive jdbc driver, they are not backward compatible, in particular between Hive 1.1.0 and 1.2.0. It does not make much sense to query Hive from Spark via JDBC since Spark can use a direct connection.